# google drive api Can't load children of a folder

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

In google drive api I am trying to retrieve children of a folder by providing folderId. I get an error

```
Cannot read property 'list' of undefined
```

as children is undefined in the line below

```
gapi.client.drive.children.list
```

I am providing all the scopes mentioned in the try it example [here](http://gapi.client.drive.childre)

Is this could be due to discover doc's which i have:  var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest"];

I have also tried to use get to the following url and getting 401

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'+ folderId +'/children;
```

Any idea what could be the cause this issue. Let me know if i should provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

`gapi.client.drive.children.list` is a v2 endpoint. You're using v3. The equivalent is a [`files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) with a `q={folder_id}` in parents. More v3 equivalents are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration).